# Firefox "jQuery is not defined" error in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm using asp.net mvc also using jQuery ui dialog, i'm showing a partialview in a jQuery dialog but Firefox give me an error on these two files below. I post an Ajax.BeginForm() to server. on first post it's working fine but on sencond post it destroys my dialog.

- jquery.validate.min.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Error : jQuery is not defined

**I dont have this problem in IE**, please help.

```
@model MvcSmkApplication.Models.LoginModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AuthenticateUser", "Members", new AjaxOptions
{
HttpMethod = "POST",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "LoginForm",
OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
}))
{

<div id="LoginForm">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        @foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
            {         
            <div style="color: Red;">@error.ErrorMessage</div>
            }
        }
        <div style="float: right;">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="buttonAsLink" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">

function OnSuccess(e) { 
    if (e["success"] == "true") {
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        location.reload();
    }
    else {
        //alert('error');
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the HTML source in FF? Please check if the path to the script files are correct. Also try to access the scripts by using the path from the source and paste it into the browser.

Comment: Have you referenced jquery and jquery UI as well in your page? Can't see them anywhere in the code you provided. Maybe they are referenced in your layout? If this is the case have you verified with FireBug that the path you provided to those scripts is correct and that the server doesn't return 404 errors?

Comment: Yes, they are in layout and the path is correct. I used @Url.content but result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution which I found it after 3 weeks research.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function OnSuccess(e) { 
    if (e["success"] == "true") {
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        location.reload();
    }
    else {
        $("#dialog").html(e);
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try referencing your scripts like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, both ways generate something like this: <script src=/Scripts/...

Comment: gibson
can you please take a look at my all new comments.

Comment: @CaseyWilliams @scottm  Hi guys, can you please take a look at my issue.